# open cygwin.bat using Excel VBA's `Shell` and execute command

Tags: excel, vba, cygwin

Is there a way to open cygwin.bat using Excel VBA's `Shell` command and execute commands?

For ex;

How do I execute `head data.csv` through Excel VBA's `Shell`?
The following doesn't work;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim out, cmd As Variant
    cmd = "C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat" & "head data.csv"
    out = Shell(cmd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `head.exe` directly in your call to `Shell`. It is in the `cygwin/bin` directory.

Comment: I've used `head` just as an example. I have reasons for using `Cygwin.bat`.

Comment: You can provide arguments if you call `bash.exe --login` (which is what `cygwin.bat` mainly does) as in http://superuser.com/questions/562112/how-to-escape-the-arguments-correctly-when-calling-cygwin-bash-c?rq=1